# Application with CloudKit and Coredata for the local storage. How to cope with the order of CKSubscritpion notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cloudkit

Hello I have created a macOS cocoa application that uses Cloudkit, and Coredata to store a local copy of the storage. My application has an 'item' record which stores CKReferences to 'subitems'. The local storage is maintained through the use of CKSubscription notifications that trigger Core Data code for the creation/update of the local objects. The issue is that if I create a new item with subitems and later launch the app on another Mac, it can be that the other copy receives the sub-item creation notification earlier than the item's. Thus the code receives the sub-item but there is no corresponding Core Data object yet available at that point. Does anybody imagine a good pattern to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the sync api. Apple recommends you use subscriptions only to get notified that something has changed not what. When you receive a notification fetch all changes that have been made since the last update.

Answer (score 0):

Apple faces this same issue with the Notes app where they have folders containing notes, and notes containing attachments i.e. they cannot download a note that is in a folder that doesn't exist yet. How they solve it is using a private class `CKRecordGraph` and the method `+ (id)topologicallySortRecords:(id)arg1 withError:(id *)arg2;` which sorts based on the `CKReference`s so they ensure they upload the folders before the notes that are inside (i.e. have a reference to the containing folder). Since the client will download the changes in order, it would be impossible for another client to download the note before the folder. You might also want to experiment with placeholder objects so you create the object  but then fill in the info later. You could experiment by using the private class and then provide your own basic implementation perhaps customised for your own entities, e.g. always order the parent entities before the children. Here is the header for `CKRecordGraph` maybe one day it'll be public (I submitted feedback FB6117775 requesting it).

```
//
//     Generated by class-dump 3.5-MH (64 bit).
//
//     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2015 by Steve Nygard.
//

#import <objc/NSObject.h>

@class NSArray, NSMutableArray;

@interface CKRecordGraph : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *_nodes;
    NSArray *_sortedRecords;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *nodes; // @synthesize nodes=_nodes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sortedRecords; // @synthesize sortedRecords=_sortedRecords;

+ (id)topologicallySortRecords:(id)arg1 withError:(id *)arg2;
- (BOOL)addRecords:(id)arg1 error:(id *)arg2;
- (id)description;
- (id)init;
- (id)recordsByTopologicalSortWithError:(id *)arg1;

@end
```